# Coffeescript: I can't seem to select an element by ID + child class

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to select a **div** where **class**= `pick1-box` given only the **ID** of a parent using **Coffeescript**.

```
jQuery(document).ready ->

  pick1value = $('#vote_pick1_id').val
  $("#" + pick1value + " .pick1-box").css('background-color', 'green')
```

I can verify that `pick1value` has received a value from `$('#vote_pick1_id').val`

```
...
<li class='nominee clearfix' id='146'>
  <div class='candidate'>
    <img alt="Enders" height="80" src="/assets/25803sm.jpg" />
    Dick Waddington
  </div>
  <div class='pick-boxes'>
    <div class='pick1-box'>
      1
    </div>
    <div class='pick2-box'>
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
...
```

FWIW: `$("#" + pick1value)` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: fyi `jQuery(document).ready ->` can be written `$ ->`

Comment: ID's cannot start with numbers, I would start by fixing that.

Comment: What value does `pick1value` contain?  I don't see anything with an `id` attribute that also has a `pick1-box` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

```
pick1value = $('#vote_pick1_id').val
```

should be this...

```
pick1value = $('#vote_pick1_id').val()
```

because you're not passing arguments.

Right now you're assigning the *function* itself to the variable instead of calling it.

---

Pretty sure your `.css()` call could eliminate the `()` though...

```
$("#" + pick1value + " .pick1-box").css 'background-color', 'green'
```

Comment: btw- this fails pretty cryptically (`jquery.min.js:3error:Syntax error:unrecognized expression #` and `message: "Can't find variable: thisMonth"` where I make no reference to `thisMonth` in this app?!?) when the `val()` is null. I put a quick `if pick1value.length > 0` in front of the assignment and it seems to be happy. **Let me know if you know a better NULL check or can think of a way offhand to build a selector that won't error out when the pick1value == null.**

Comment: @Meltemi: That's very strange that you should get an error. The selector would just concatentate `"null"` or `"undefined"` into the selector, so no match would be found, which means it should fail silently. Your `if` test is fine, but you could actually get rid of the `> 0` since a `0` length will be considered false.